Issues with hierarchy in kotlin
I have a TextElement class with a class level variable valled textGravity which is being initialized with default value Element.HorizontalGravity.DEFAULT
In the constructor of TextElement, I'm calling the super constructor of the parent class Element and in that constructor the textGravity variable got his value. I know this is not a good practice, but it's an inherited project with these kind of structure which cannot be changed for now due to more complex parameters I can't explain here.
The problem is that after textGravity being setted in the parent decode method of the parent Element class... the setted value is being loss, because for some reason I don't understand, is reseted to default because this line of the children TextElement class is called again afther the super constructor:
var textGravity = Element.HorizontalGravity.DEFAULT

Why that happens? How is that possible and how can I avoid that?
class TextElement : Element {
    var textGravity = Element.HorizontalGravity.DEFAULT

    constructor(binaryReader: BinaryReader) : super(binaryReader) {
        decode(binaryReader)
    }
}


open class Element {
    constructor(reader: BinaryReader) {
        this.decode(reader)
    }
    private fun decode(reader: BinaryReader) {
        if (this is TextElement) {
            (this as TextElement).textGravity = Element.HorizontalGravity.MIDDLE
        }
    }
}   


decode() is private in Element, so the subclass TextElement cannot call it. If decode() is actually protected, note that you are calling decode() twice, once in the superclass and once in the subclass. "Why that happens?" -- the superclass constructor will be executed before property initializers or init blocks of subclasses.

@CommonsWare both decodes are independent, not the same, I know it's wrong, but again it's an inherited big project which I cannot perfectionate. "the superclass constructor will be executed before property initializers or init blocks of subclasses" That's the point! that is breaking it. In the java version this doesn't happen. How can I solve this?

"How can I solve this?" -- I am not aware that you can. "In the java version this doesn't happen" -- it should, insofar as I am fairly certain that Java superclass constructors are called before subclass field initializers execute. Otherwise you would not be able to reliably class superclass methods from those subclass field initializers.

@CommonsWare thanks to you I double checked the java code and I observed a difference, on java, I was not initializing the variable. So I changed the variable to a lateinit one in kotlin: lateinit var textGravity: Element.HorizontalGravity and it started working.

The constructor of the superclass will be invoked before property initializers in the subclass. That is unavoidable. It is what allows those property initializers to call functions reliably on the superclass, for example.
Per your comment, you switched to lateinit var and got rid of the subclass' own property initializer. That will require one of two things to be true:

The superclass always sets that property. It does in your question, but I assume that the real code is more complex than this. 

Or, you need to guard your use of that property using something like ::textGravity.isInitialized, so you do not try to use it if you have not initialized it. For example, I think that you could have an init block after the property declaration/initializer that double-checks that the property was initialized and, if it does not, initializes it.


As you note in the question, this code is kinda scary overall, and you are stuck with it. Others reading this question in the future () might try to rework matters so that the superclass is not trying to mess with subclass properties in the superclass constructor this way.

"try to rework matters so that the superclass is not trying to mess with subclass properties in the superclass constructor this way" <--- exactly! thank you
